# AngularJS variable not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A question that has been asked (and answered) a thousand times, yet I can't figure this out.

I'm trying to update the option labels of a select box based on the value of another.

Select code for the source of the new label:

```
<select id="year" name="year" ng-model="Data.year" ng-change="updateAge(Data.year)">
```

Option value code for the target of the new label

```
<option value="low">{{ Age.low }}</option>
```

Controller code to update the scope variable. The second console log displays the updated age, but that isn't shown in the view. I've tried `$scope.$apply()` but Angular errors because $apply is already in progress.

```
$scope.updateAge = function( year ) {
    if ( year == '2016' ) {
        console.log($scope.Age.low);
        $scope.Age.low = 'NEW AGE';
        console.log($scope.Age.low);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you display ```Data.year``` in the new label instead of ```Age.low```?

Comment: Just updated the updateAge function. I'm trying to change the age based on the year in the first select box.

Comment: I am starting to understand less and less of your goal. You want to display the selected year but only if it is 2016? Can you please explain it clearly once again?

Comment: If the year is 2016, I want the Age.low variable to be "Under 65", for example. If it's 2017, I want it to show in the view as "Under 69".  So {{ Age.low }} needs to be updated dependant on the value of Data.year.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As you set the option value as "low". Hence, on `updateAge` function call  this block `if ( year == '2016' ) { ... }` will not execute because `year` value will always be `low`.
- Make `option` value also dynamic.

  **try** `<option value="{{ Age.low }}">{{ Age.low }}</option>`

  **instead of** `<option value="low">{{ Age.low }}</option>`

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Age = {"low": '2016'};
    $scope.updateAge = function(year) {
    if (year == '2016') {
        console.log($scope.Age.low);
        $scope.Age.low = 'NEW AGE';
        console.log($scope.Age.low);
    }   
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id="year" name="year" ng-model="Data.year" ng-change="updateAge(Data.year)">
  <option value="{{ Age.low }}">{{ Age.low }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```